# String compression algorithm using functional JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, compression

I've written an algo to compress a string

eg. aabcbbba to a2bcb3a

I'm pretty new to functional programming, I feel it's easier to debug and learn from functional code if you're good at it already, but total opposite if you're not.

I'm wondering how I can make this code cleaner and more functional.

I feel like there's gotta be a better way to do compressCharacters without the need of an array or a result variable (perhaps substituting forEach with something else) as well as reducing the lines of code in groupCharacters

```js
const signature = `aabcbbba`;

const compressString = signature => {
  return compressCharacters(groupCharacters(signature));
}

const groupCharacters = signature => {
  let newSignature = "", arr = [];
  
  // convert signature to an array
  let result = [...signature].reduce((accumulator, element, index) => {
    
    // check if last letter in accumulator matches the current element
    if (accumulator[accumulator.length -1] !== element) {
      // add the accumulator string into an array
      arr.push(accumulator);
      // clear the newSignature string and set it to current element
      newSignature = element;
    } else {
      // if it doesn't match, add it to the accumulator
      newSignature = accumulator += element;
    }
    
    // check if it's the last item - add to array
    if (index === signature.length - 1) arr.push(element);
    
    // return newSignature to accumulator
    return newSignature;
  })

  return arr;
}

const compressCharacters = arr => {
  let newArray = [];

  let result = arr.forEach(e => e.length > 1 ? newArray.push(`${e[0]}${e.length}`) : newArray.push(e))

  return newArray.join("");
}

compressString(signature);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Style notes

- Not putting `{`, `}` around single line statement blocks is a bad habit. Always delimit statement code blocks.
- In `compressCharacters` `newArray` should be a constant. In `groupCharacters` `arr` should be a constant.
- Consistent naming is important. Your naming is all over the place. You call a string, characters (in `compressCharacters`), string (in `compressString`), `signature`, and `e` in the `forEach`. A character you call `element`. You abbreviate an array to `arr` in one function and call it `newArray` in another. Most of the names are describing the type and not the abstracted data that they hold.
- Don't add useless or redundant code. In `compressCharacters` you create a variable `result` that you do nothing with. Not to mention that `forEach` does not have a return defined. Also `result` in `groupCharacters` is never used.
- Don't declare variables outside the scope that they are to be used. `newSignature` is only used inside `reduce` but declared outside the callback.

Functional programing means that functions should not have side effect (change the state of anything outside the function's scope.) The `reduce` callback uses the array `arr` which breaks the no side effects rule. And the `forEach` pushes to `arr` which is also outside the `forEach` callbacks scope (use `map` or `reduce` in that case).

Applying the above you would get something like the following code.

```
const groupRuns = str => [...str].reduce((groups, char) => {
        const last = groups.length - 1;
        if (last < 0 || groups[last][0] !== char) { groups.push(char) }
        else { groups[last] += char }
        return groups;
    }, []);

const concatGroups = groups => groups.reduce((str, g) => 
        str + (g.length > 2 ? g[0] + g.length : g)
    , "");

const compressString = str => concatGroups(groupRuns(str));

const signature = `aabcbbbaaaaaabcccccdddddddbbba`;
compressString(signature);
```

Note that rather than add numbers to groups of size 2 the group must be 3 or larger.

Comment: `g.length > 2` is wrong: it fails to transform `aa` to `a2` as specified.

Comment: @200_success As I pointed out.

Comment: shouldn't concatGroups also be delimited with brackets and returns?

Comment: @totalnoob It is not required, in fact `groupRuns` can do without the return. However I should have moved the returning object to the same line. I will update it now.

Comment: doesn't that go against "Not putting {, } around single line statement blocks is a bad habit. Always delimit statement code blocks."?

Comment: @totalnoob Well yes I guess it does. Thought it is a function block not a statement block and it's not an easy mistake to make if you add another line to the function you will be wanting move the return position so you will be quite aware that the `{`, `}` needs to be added, including the `return` token. With statement blocks its very easy to add another line  and forget the `{`, `}`  And they can create very hard to spot bugs in a large code base.

Comment: The regex `/(.)\1+/g` would match all the substrings that need replacing. I suspect this could be a one-liner with a `match` and a `reduce`. Not going to type it up as an answer since it wouldn't really be a code review :)

Comment: @JollyJoker Agreed, I did think of a ground up rewrite, including decompress but the OP's question lacked scope. What characters are to be compressed? What to do with digits in the string? Does the compressed string have transport limitations (UTF-8, UCS-2, or raw bin)? Expected size range, and more? You can post your version as a performance review, RegExp's are almost always more performant than handwritten searches.

Comment: @JollyJoker, could you show me how you'd use RegExp for the substrings in like a jsfiddle, please?

Comment: @totalnoob Very simple... extending from JollyJoker's.comment the function would be `const compressString = str => str.replace(/(.)\1+/g, str => str[0] + str.length);`  and used like so `compressString("aabcbbba");` returns "a2bcb3a"

Comment: very nice. how does the (.) and \1+ work?

Comment: The parenthesis defines a capturing group, with the dot matching any one character. The \1 refers to that captured group, so (.)\1 is any character repeated twice. The plus is "or more". Use an [online regex tester](https://www.regextester.com/) to figure things out

Comment: @Blindman67 Even simpler than I thought. As a code review comment; you're using the name `str` for two different things.